# join 78 specific codes from created table to linked table. Can't use IN() function (character limit), Can't do RI

Tags: sql, ms-access, join

I have a DB (Access 2010) that I am pulling data from, but I am trying to make it easier to pull specific cases instead of mucking about in Excel.

We have about 78 product type codes that we classify as a certain account type. Unfortunately I can't use an IN() function because there are too many characters (there is the 1024 char limit). I looked online for help and it was suggested that I make a table to inner join on the product codes that I want.

I created a table with the codes I want to pull, then joined on the productcodetype in the linked database table. Unfortunately when I run the sql nothing shows up, just blank. I tried different join combinations to no avail, read up further and found that you can't enforce referential integrity on linked DB tables from non-linked DB tables.

I think this is my problem but I'm not sure, and I don't know if I'm using the right language, but I can't find a similar issue to mine so I'm hoping it's an easy fix and I'm just not thinking about it the right way.

Is there any way to select certain cases (78 product type codes) from a large database using something like IN() or a reference table when I can't create a new table in the linked db?

Thank you,
K

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must to use two tables and build a query that join them. If your join don't return any result, be sure that the joined fields are of the same data type and realy share the same values.

If your data source is Excel, be sure that there isn't any trailing blanks or other 'invisible' character.

Comment: Thanks mnieto! I actually double checked my productcode list that I pasted in from Excel when making the table. I didn't find any errors but I found that even though RI wasn't enforced, the table had matched up with all of the related product codes. So it made me think why it wasn't showing up. I recreated the query and it turns out there is a bug(?) that nothing shows up if you put anything number in the 'Max Records' property. Leaving it blank actually populated my query, whereas when I put a max of 200 cases nothing showed up. Weird.